# How can I fix the pattern of regex to match with size

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, list

I am using this pattern

```
var pattern = @"\[([^\]]+)\] \[?([^\(\]]+)(?:\(((\w\s)+)\))?\]?.*?(?:\s*NOT\s*NULL)?(?:,|$)";
```

and here is my code

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(command, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var fieldName = match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
    var dataType = match.Groups[2].Value.Trim();
    var sizeStr = match.Groups[3].Value.Trim();
```

I am always getting null value for sizeStr how can I modify my pattern or is there any other way around this is the input that I want to give

Example command format:

```
[field1] [dataType1] (20) nullability, [field2] [dataType2] (max) nullability, [field3] [dataType3] nullability
```

I have tried chatgpt and blackbox ai both are not going anywhere with my problem so I am kind of stuck!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of optional parts in your regex like optional brackets, and you are also repeating a capture group `(\w\s)+` that matches a single character followed by a single whitspace char.

This part is also optional `(?:\s*NOT\s*NULL)?` and not in a capture group, so if you want 3 capture groups, you can write the pattern as:

```
\[([^\]]+)]\s+\[([^(\]]+)](?:\s*\(\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*\))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[([^\]]+)]` Capture in **group 1** what is in between `[..]`
- `\s+\[([^(\]]+)]` Match 1+ whitespace chars and capture in **group 2** what is in between `[..]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
  - `\(\s*` Match `(` and optional whitespace chars
  - `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` Capture in **group 3**  matching 1+ whitespace chars and optionally repeat 1+ whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
  - `\s*\)` Match optional whitespace chars and match `)`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RgZt89/1)

As group 3 is now optional, you can check for the existence in the code.

---

If group 3 should always be there when there is a match, and if for example what is in between the parenthesis can also be empty, you can make the inner part of the group optional.

In this case it will also match the surrounding parenthesis:

```
\[([^\]]+)]\s+\[([^(\]]+)]\s*((?:\([\w\s]*\))?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGnJtv/1)